# How to inject Dependency injection manually

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to inject a service using service provider here which is register in program.cs but service provider is null. How can I inject in this class as I don't have constructor scenario here.

```
public partial class Dto : IValidatableObject {
public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider;
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) {

        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        // Calling service below causing serviceProvider null
        var service = (ISCService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ISCService));
            service.GetData();
```

I am trying with injecting in method using fromservice but not luck

```
public bool IsIdExist([FromServices] ISCService service) {
    var site = service.GetIdAsync();
    if (site == null) { return false; }
    return true;
```

Comment: What is `serviceProvider`?

Comment: @GuruStron edited with some more code snap to clarify it better

Comment: Where it is set?

Comment: @GuruStron That is where I am struggling to set to inject the service. Is there a way to do it. Actually I want to inject my service in model to validate the Dtos. I know its not the best way to call service in model but we have this scenario to do

Comment: Don't do it in Dto. What is the purpose of this ISCService service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `IValidatableObject` is from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` - you don't need to inject anything into the `Dto`, use services from the provided `ValidationContext`:

```cs
class Dto : IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var iscService = validationContext.GetRequiredService<ISCService>(); // add using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; 
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yay! Thank you @GuruStron. your code has solved my issue :)